# Firebase web push notification onclick when the tab is in focus

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I'm looking for a way to handle `onclick` event on a [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification), when the app is in foreground and tab is in focus.

I have this:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {....
```

in my service worker file `firebase-messaging-sw.js`, but this only gets triggered when the app is in the background or not in focus. I think this is how it's supposed to work.

Earlier I was doing this:

```
const options = {
              body: notification.body,
              click_action: notification.data.click_action,
              data: notification.data,
              tag: tag
            };

const notif = new Notification(notification.title, options);

notif.onclick = function() {
    alert('sdfsdf'); // working FINE
};
```

However, `new Notification` doesn't seem to be working at all in Android based browsers like chrome, brave, firefox, etc.

Now I'm using this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function() { ....
```

to find my service worker registration (`ServiceWorkerRegistration` interface) and call `showNotification` method on it, which is working fine cross-platform.

**But how do I bind the `onclick` on `Notification` that `showNotification` generates**

I tried doing this:

```
// v = ServiceWorkerRegistration

v.getNotifications({ tag: tag })
         .then(function(notificationsList) {
            if( notif = notificationsList[0] ) {
              console.log("notif: ", notif);

              notif.onclick = function() {
                  alert('new notif');
                };
            }
  });
```

the `onclick` gets bind, but still doesn't work.

I might be missing something here.